# Image seems to be added to bucket, can't view it on my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I just implemented paperclip in to my rails app that's hosted on heroku.  The app seemingly connects and uploads the image to s3.  Here are some examples of the logs when I submit the form on the app:

```
2013-06-01T17:52:45.112448+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2/vRFLrAnBnokNwohVfMhG74d3HN0/GTwype2jGJm9w=", "illustration"=>{"name"=>"Test", "illustrator"=>"Test", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000050d9a58 @original_filename="DEISIGN_Cover_Illustration.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"illustration[image]\"; filename=\"DEISIGN_Cover_Illustration.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20130601-12-v7uo9s>>, "edition_id"=>"17", "tag_list"=>"Test", "description"=>"Test"}, "commit"=>"Update Illustration", "id"=>"199"}
2013-06-01T17:52:45.113280+00:00 app[web.1]: [AWS S3 200 0.424977 0 retries] head_object(:bucket_name=>"haggard",:key=>"illustrations/images/000/000/199/original/DEISIGN_Cover_Illustration.jpg")  
2013-06-01T17:52:45.113496+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-01T17:52:45.113496+00:00 app[web.1]: [AWS S3 200 0.085094 0 retries] head_object(:bucket_name=>"haggard",:key=>"illustrations/images/000/000/199/thumb/DEISIGN_Cover_Illustration.jpg")  
2013-06-01T17:52:45.113496+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-01T17:52:45.624956+00:00 app[web.1]: [AWS S3 204 0.099689 0 retries] delete_object(:bucket_name=>"haggard",:key=>"illustrations/images/000/000/199/original/DEISIGN_Cover_Illustration.jpg")  
2013-06-01T17:52:45.624956+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-01T17:52:45.715606+00:00 app[web.1]: [AWS S3 204 0.09001 0 retries] delete_object(:bucket_name=>"haggard",:key=>"illustrations/images/000/000/199/thumb/DEISIGN_Cover_Illustration.jpg")  
2013-06-01T17:52:45.715606+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-01T17:52:46.835310+00:00 app[web.1]: [AWS S3 200 1.116787 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"haggard",:content_length=>575121,:content_type=>"image/jpeg",:data=>Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter: DEISIGN_Cover_Illustration.jpg,:key=>"illustrations/images/000/000/199/original/DEISIGN_Cover_Illustration.jpg")  
2013-06-01T17:52:46.835310+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-01T17:52:47.011793+00:00 app[web.1]: [AWS S3 200 0.173532 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"haggard",:content_length=>6096,:content_type=>"image/jpeg",:data=>Paperclip::FileAdapter: DEISIGN_Cover_Illustration20130601-12-6ldegn20130601-12-1ytcjd0,:key=>"illustrations/images/000/000/199/thumb/DEISIGN_Cover_Illustration.jpg")  
2013-06-01T17:52:47.011793+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-01T17:52:47.020929+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://visualhaggard.org/illustrations/199
```

The image I've uploaded appears in my S3 bucket console.

My view uses `@illustration.image.url` to get the image to display.

I am not setting the permissions anywhere for the image.  Are they automatically set appropriately for the app to upload and download the image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set all your images as **public** in your **s3 bucket**. If images are set to private by-default. If images are private you wont be able to see images.

Secondly, set all credential of your s3 bucket.

In **config/s3.yml file set s3 credential as

```
development:
 access_key_id: your_access_key_id
 secret_access_key: your_access_key
 bucket: your_bucket_name
production:
 access_key_id: your_access_key_id
 secret_access_key: your_access_key
 bucket: your_bucket_name
```

Then in **config/initializers/s3.rb** file initialise all images as

```
if Rails.env == "production"
 # set credentials from ENV hash
 S3_CREDENTIALS = { :access_key_id => ENV['access_key_id'], :secret_access_key => ENV['secret_key'], :bucket => "bucket_name"}
else
 # get credentials from YML file
 S3_CREDENTIALS = Rails.root.join("config/s3.yml")
end
```